# Semantic UI Resizing Divider Parts?

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am using Divider component from Semantic-ui for dividing a segment vertically, it divides the segment 50/50 i think is there way to make it 70/30 60/40 basically whichever i like ? Thanks for help!

Comment: Hi! Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in a Segment component by adding a grid and change width props from  Grid.column  like this:

```
<Segment>
    <Grid stackable>
      <Grid.Column width={4}>
        <Image src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png" />
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column>
        <Divider vertical> or </Divider>
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column width={9}>
        <Image src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/paragraph.png" />
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
  </Segment>
```

[image: Edit semantic-ui-example (forked)]